# Finding the range of $\frac{5 \cos x-2 \sin ^{2} x+4 \sin x-3}{6|\cos x|+1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, trigonometry

Here is the expression:
\begin{equation}
\frac{5 \cos x-2 \sin ^{2} x+4 \sin x-3}{6|\cos x|+1}
\end{equation}

I have tried to maximize the denominator, so I got the maximum value of denominator equal to 7, but I am lost what to do next

I did the graph of this expression, so the minimum value is equal to -9, but how to get the answer without a graph, which is difficult to do by hand?

Comment: Do you know calculus or do you want a trigonometry-only solution? With calculus you would just differentiate and find where the derivative is zero.

Comment: Well I know calculus, it´s powerful, but this time I desire trigonometry-only solution.

Comment: I don't think there is a trigonometry-only solution for the maximum value. The minimum is easy to find.

Comment: How to find minimum?

Comment: I've posted a partial answer showing just how to get the minimum.

Comment: I don't see a way to find the maximum without calculus... partly because graphing gives a maximum that isn't at $x=a\pi/b$.  There might be some weird way around this with $u=\sin x, v =\cos x, u=v\tan x$... but outlook is hazy.

Answer (score 6):

If $x\in[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ then $|\cos x|=\cos x$ so
\begin{equation}
\frac{5 \cos x-2 \sin ^{2} x+4 \sin x-3}{6|\cos x|+1}
={5\cos x+5/6\over6\cos x+1}+{-2\sin^2 x+ 4\sin x -3\frac56\over6\cos x+1}\\
=5/6+{-2\sin^2 x+ 4\sin x -3\frac56\over6\cos x+1}\\
\end{equation}
The $-2\sin^2 x$ term is always negative, so let $x=-\pi/2$ then $\sin x=-1$, $\cos x=0$, and so by inspection it is clearly the minimum and the value is $-9$.

You can apply the same argument to the other range $x\in[\pi/2, 3\pi/2]$ and the same minimum is found.